# Get list of logged in users PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, session

I am creating a simple real time chat application , so i have to show the `chatBuddyList` on the right side of the page.

Currently i have 2 tables for users, `tbl_users` (`user_id`,name,email...) and `tbl_logged_user` (id,`user_id`).

on user login i will insert the `user_id` to the `tbl_logged_users` and in logout i am removing that record.

everything is fine , but the problem is with `Logout`. when users clicks on `logout` link it will work,but sometime the user may automatically logged out due to session expiration,browser close etc ...

How can i handle such situations ? and what will be the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks.

> I am trying to find the best method for this , simply because the exact application is not a real chat based one , i have a table/s with average of `80,000` records. And polling/comet is running about 5-10 seconds of time frame.

**EDIT**

There are some answers saying about `session_id`. I believe that its not useful becuase session time out php cannot automatically update the database table unless there is a new request.

Comment: I've done this before. To catch something like this, it is necessary to write a timestamp with the last contact with the client in the database and test whether that is older than x seconds.

Comment: @fnkr what about `idle` user.

Comment: you can implement the [SessionHandlerInterface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php). In your [destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandlerinterface.destroy.php) method you can update the database using the session_id().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is not the "usual" way of solving the problem, but I think it is not a bad solution:

You can use a websocket with a tiny Node.js server for example. When a user loads the page with a valid session, it connects to the server (just two lines with javascript). When it disconnects (closes the page) the websocket brokens and the server catches the event.

If the user closes the browser, the socket disconnects. If the user clicks logout, the page reloads and then the socket is not created again (no valid session). The only problem comes when the user leaves the browser open for a long time and session expires. Well, adding a timeout in the server would solve this.

If you are creating a chat application try websockets, you won't regret.

Comment: Thanks for the brute force , i was thinking to avoid something like this only because of i am not aware of it. Let me think about `Node.js`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the session checker code in my chat application.
$CONFIG["app:maxLatency"] is time in seconds. After this time, the client will be logged out if he did not contact the server.
You need a table called users with id (integer), lastseen (timestamp) and sid (session id, text)

Sample table:

```
id     |   lastseen                |  sid
--------------------------------------------------
123    |   2013-03-11 11:00:00     |  abcdefg12345
```

Sample code:

```
function DeleteSessionByUserId($user_id) {
    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
    global $CONFIG;

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET sid = '' WHERE id = '".$user_id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return true;
}

// This will delete all users with expired sessions
function CheckAllSessionsExpired() {
    global $CONFIG;

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE sid != '' AND lastseen < '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-".$CONFIG["app:maxLatency"]." seconds"))."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        DeleteSessionByUserId($line['id']);
    }
    return true;
}

// This will update the last seen timestamp in MySQL
function UserSetSeen($user_id) {
    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);

    global $CONFIG;
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastseen = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE id = '".$user_id."';";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `CheckAllSessionsExpired` will kill all my `idle` users.

Comment: Did you run UserSetSeen($user_id) every time the client contacts the server? I use JavaScript to refresh the messages every 1 second.

Comment: Thanks for the effort , technically its Ok. But its not practical in my case , just think about a internet connection lose , so it will fail to update the  `timestamp` , also i cannot run more than 2 polls on page.

Comment: Every time the client contacts the server run `UserSetSeen`. That will update the lastseen timestamp. Now, if the user dont contacts the server for `$CONFIG["app:maxLatency"]` time in seconds the user will be logged out - no matter why (no internet connection, browser closed, ...).   No Internet connection for more than `$CONFIG["app:maxLatency"]` ==> logout. Browser close ==> logout.

Comment: Do i need to do the update against all users ? becuase `user3` is doing nothing , so i cannot update the timestamp.

Comment: You need a script that contacts the server every second or so. You can also add a background frame.

Answer (score 1):

Store session id in table while logging and keep checking the session id at regular interval, to state user is online, if user closes browser session id wont match then logout the user.

Comment: can you explain it? how to check session_id ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a user logged in, if he was active in the last 5 minutes (or so). That's the way almost every website handles it.
You can just register a timestamp every time the user "does" something (i.e. sending a message in your chatbox)

Comment: Thanks for the idea , but is it a reliable way in case of chat application ? ex : assume that there are 3 users. `User1` and `User2` chatting each other and `User3` is `idle`, all these 3 people can see 3 users on chatList,now `User3` is logged out in a session timeout, how can i handle this ? any idea?

Comment: You could update the timestamp again on the Ajax refresh if it's more than 4 minutes since the last timestamp update.

Comment: There is no waterproof way to register it. In the case you are "polling" the webserver for new messages (with ajax) every few seconds, you could set your timeout @ 30 secs for example

Comment: For some reasons i cannot do another call for checking all users log state.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a status to the users table. Update the status to 1 on login and reset to 0 on log out. Then select all results from the users table where status = 1 using AJAX every 5 or 10 seconds. Make a users_online div and display the results.

Answer (score -1):

if you're maintaining sessions in a table, just count the number of active sessions in the table.

Comment: Can you explain little more ? ( i hope that this is an answer )

Comment: Session table is not reliable. When the user is closing his window, your session table will not be updated until you "expire" the session (with PHP's default timeout for example)

Comment: Are you using a framework? Where do your sessions go? In the filesystem or a db? If it is a filesystem you could do $sessionCount = count(glob(session_save_path()."/*"));

Comment: Use a session wrapper so that you get complete control of your sessions. Use something like: http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-session/

Comment: MySQL is not really a good way of storing sessions. Try using Redis/MongoDB/Memcache

Comment: I need more reliable results ,I am using FILESYSTEM and DATABSE with Codeigniter framework.

Comment: If you need extremely accurate results, use a WebSocket solution. Try Slanger or Pusher (http://www.pusherapp.com). Include the js on every page and subscribe the user to a channel. On successful connection, update a record in the db with the correct count. Once the window is closed, the user is unsubscribed and again you can hook your code to go ahead and update the db count. And thus you get completely accurate point-in-time online user count.